# Splitting string with "\\s".toRegex() is not working in Kotlin

Tags: android, string, kotlin

I have tried using `"\\s".toRegex()` in the following way.

```
var sentence = "test1    test2   test3"
sentence.split("\\s".toRegex())
```

It splits the string into more than 3 items(since there are spaces). But I would like the string to be divided into 3 items by not considering space.

I tried the same with `sentence.split(" +".toRegex())` it is working as expected and returning 3 items `[Test1,test2,test3]`

Why `"\\s".toRegex()` is not working?

Comment: Did you use single "\" or double "\\"? Because you first say double and then provided the code with single. I guess this is due to formatting on SO. Anyway, your code works as you expected, it returns 3 items: https://pl.kotl.in/kYejGzGzf

Comment: @broot Sorry, it was due to the formatting in SO. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for one or more matches you need to add the +, just like you did with `" +"` so if you want to use `\\s` you also add the plus like

`sentence.split("\\s+".toRegex())`

Comment: Thanks, I was confused with the usage of regex. Your answer cleared it